# Display a path of Linestrings in GeoViews

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, holoviews, geoviews

I am trying to visualize some LINESTRINGS in a Jupyter Notebook using the Path Object in Goeviews. The Path should be colorcoded by the amount of traffic (see example below).
I read the related post [Displaying Paths with Geoviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198579/displaying-paths-with-geoviews) and the given example worked for me.

However, the coloring does not seem to work for Linestrings. Am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated!

```
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
import json

import holoviews as hv
import geoviews as gv
hv.extension('bokeh')

url = 'http://stadtplan.bonn.de/geojson?Thema=19584'
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
gdf_traffic = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(data['features'])
gdf_traffic.head(1)



#'geschwindigkeit' = 'traffic' in German
%%opts Path [width=500 height=500 color_index="geschwindigkeit"] (cmap='inferno')

gv.Path(gdf_traffic, vdims=["geschwindigkeit"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue, I ended up using `hvplot` :

```
gdf_traffic.set_geometry("geometry").hvplot(
    by = "geschwindigkeit",
    tiles = "CartoLight",
    legend_position = "top_left"
)
```

[image: map result]

You’ll need to `import hvplot.pandas` [before the geodataframe is created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75602308/812102).

I’m not sure why entries are missing in the legend, didn’t look into it yet.  Not sure how to change the colormap either, there seems to be related bug reports on [HoloViz’s github](https://github.com/holoviz/hvplot/issues).

Answer (score 0):

If someone still wants to know how to colour the LineStrings, this works for me:

```
gv.Path(gdf_traffic, vdims=["geschwindigkeit"]).opts(color="yellow",line_width=2)
```

Comment: This will color all the lines in yellow, not according to `geschwindigkeit`.