# Geopandas has no attribute hvplot

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, hvplot

I am running this code to generate a choropleth map of landprices in Germany. I have installed the pyviz, panel and geoviews packages. Even yesterday this was generating the plots with the hovering annotations. But today the code is generating an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7148\2718829362.py in <module>
      3 years = pn.widgets.IntSlider(name="Jahre",value=2005,start=1995,end=2021,step=1)
      4 #interact = pn.bind(map_landvalue,zeit=years,pval=value_type)
----> 5 de_map_plot = pn.Column(pn.Column(value_type,years),
      6                     pn.bind(map_landvalue,zeit=years,pval=value_type))
      7 de_map_plot.show()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\base.py in __init__(self, *objects, **params)
    628                                  "as positional arguments or as a keyword, "
    629                                  "not both." % type(self).__name__)
--> 630             params['objects'] = [panel(pane) for pane in objects]
    631         elif 'objects' in params:
    632             params['objects'] = [panel(pane) for pane in params['objects']]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\base.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    628                                  "as positional arguments or as a keyword, "
    629                                  "not both." % type(self).__name__)
--> 630             params['objects'] = [panel(pane) for pane in objects]
    631         elif 'objects' in params:
    632             params['objects'] = [panel(pane) for pane in params['objects']]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\base.py in panel(obj, **kwargs)
     78     if kwargs.get('name', False) is None:
     79         kwargs.pop('name')
---> 80     pane = PaneBase.get_pane_type(obj, **kwargs)(obj, **kwargs)
     81     if len(pane.layout) == 1 and pane._unpack:
     82         return pane.layout[0]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\param.py in __init__(self, object, **params)
    743         if object is not None:
    744             self._validate_object()
--> 745             self._replace_pane(not self.lazy)
    746 
    747     @param.depends('object', watch=True)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\param.py in _replace_pane(self, force, *args)
    792                     new_object = Spacer()
    793                 else:
--> 794                     new_object = self.eval(self.object)
    795                 if inspect.isawaitable(new_object):
    796                     param.parameterized.async_executor(partial(self._eval_async, new_object))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\param.py in eval(self, function)
    775                 args = (getattr(dep.owner, dep.name) for dep in arg_deps)
    776                 kwargs = {n: getattr(dep.owner, dep.name) for n, dep in kw_deps.items()}
--> 777         return function(*args, **kwargs)
    778 
    779     async def _eval_async(self, awaitable):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\param\parameterized.py in _depends(*args, **kw)
    385     @wraps(func)
    386     def _depends(*args, **kw):
--> 387         return func(*args, **kw)
    388 
    389     deps = list(dependencies)+list(kw.values())

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\depends.py in wrapped(*wargs, **wkwargs)
    207         def wrapped(*wargs, **wkwargs):
    208             combined_args, combined_kwargs = combine_arguments(wargs, wkwargs)
--> 209             return function(*combined_args, **combined_kwargs)
    210     wrapped.__bound_function__ = function
    211     return wrapped

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7148\3612203928.py in map_landvalue(zeit, pval)
      7     test=df_kreise[df_kreise['Zeit']==zeit][['Kreise_Code',pval]]
      8     test=pd.merge(kreise_map,test,on='Kreise_Code',how='outer')
----> 9     fig=test.dropna().hvplot(frame_height=550,frame_width=450,
     10                      hover_cols=['Kreise','Kreise_Code','pval_baureifsLand','pval_insgesamt'],
     11                      legend=False,c=pval,title=title_str,cmap='OrRd')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5573         ):
   5574             return self[name]
-> 5575         return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5576 
   5577     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'hvplot'
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import panel as pn

df_kreise=pd.read_csv('LandpriceFF_df.csv')
kreise_map=gpd.read_file('vg2500_geo84//vg2500_krs.dbf') #not in df_kreise [15001, 3152, 3156]
kreise_map['RS']=kreise_map['RS'].astype(int)
kreise_map=kreise_map.rename(columns={'RS':'Kreise_Code','GEN':'Kreise'})
de_map=gpd.read_file('vg2500_geo84//vg2500_sta.shp')

def map_landvalue(zeit,
                  pval):
    title_str=' Germany '+pval+' Year '+str(zeit)
    if pval == 'Baureifsland Purchase Value': pval='pval_baureifsLand'
    elif pval=='Insgesamt Purchase Value': pval='pval_insgesamt'
    test=df_kreise[df_kreise['Zeit']==zeit][['Kreise_Code',pval]]
    test=pd.merge(kreise_map,test,on='Kreise_Code',how='outer')
    fig=test.dropna().hvplot(frame_height=550,frame_width=450,
                     hover_cols=['Kreise','Kreise_Code','pval_baureifsLand','pval_insgesamt'],
                     legend=False,c=pval,title=title_str,cmap='OrRd')
    return fig

pn.extension()
value_type=pn.widgets.Select(options=['Baureifsland Purchase Value','Insgesamt Purchase Value'])
years = pn.widgets.IntSlider(name="Jahre",value=2005,start=1995,end=2021,step=1)
de_map_plot = pn.Column(pn.Column(value_type,years),
                                pn.bind(map_landvalue,zeit=years,pval=value_type))
de_map_plot.show()
```

The datasets I am using are here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VolkaneicFox/IWH-Research/main/LandpriceFF_df.csv

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/VolkaneicFox/IWH-Research/main/vg2500_krs.shp

Comment: Please provide the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors. Additionally, please fix the [formatting](/help/formatting) in your code block so the indentation is correct and provide a [mre] - at minimum make sure all imports and variables are defined. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thanks for letting me know, I hope I have provided the necessary corrections

Comment: What’s `pn`? It isn’t defined anywhere

Comment: Did you `import hvplot.pandas` before doing anything else? You need to do this before the dataframe is created to make sure it has the hvplot extension enabled. See https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Plotting_Extensions.html

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Thank you! I thought because I was importing pandas I did not have to import hvplot.pandas separately. Sorry, pn is import panel as pn

Comment: @VFox I've added that import to the question because people don't always read the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the holoviews pandas extension with `df.hviews` methods, you must `import hvplot.pandas`*before the dataframe is created*, even if you are never going to use the `hvplot.pandas` module directly.

`hvplot.pandas` is a critical import as it loads a holoviews pandas extension and registers holoviews with the pandas library so that dataframes created using pandas will have access to the `DataFrame.hviews` attribute. Without this import, your regular pandas dataframes will not have the extension loaded and attempting to use the extension will simply raise an `AttributeError`.

Note that `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` is a subclass of `pandas.DataFrame` and the above applies directly to geopandas as well. As with pandas, when reading a GeoDataFrame in from disk, the extension must be loaded before the read is called (before the geopandas object is created - but not necessarily before the file was written).

See the [hvplot extension user guide](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Plotting_Extensions.html) for more info.